# Properties of Big $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: asymptotics

I have seen in a paper that, if $A=\mathcal{O}(p^2)$ and $B=\mathcal{O}(p)$ then,

how can we say that, $A^{-1/2}B$ is diverging?

The way I thought is,

if $A = \mathcal{O}(p^2)$, then $A^{-1/2}$ = $\mathcal{O}(p^{-1})$, then $A^{-1/2}B$ = $\mathcal{O}(p^{-1})\mathcal{O}(p) = \mathcal{O}(1)$. If so, we can't say it is diverging?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you refer the paper you have seen?

Comment: Taking $A=p^2$ and $B=p$ gives a counterexample. Perhaps it was a small o?

Comment: @ Marc: The paper is Large covariance estimation by thresholding principal orthogonal complements. In that it is an example given in page 13.

Comment: @ Giulio: It is not small o. As in the paper it is O(p)

Comment: Note that if $A\in \mathcal{O}(p^2)$, then you generally don't have $A^{-1/2} \in \mathcal{O}(p^{-1})$, but $A^{-1/2} \in \Omega(p^{-1})$. Now, the product of functions from $\Omega(g)$ and $\mathcal{O}(h)$ can be pretty much anything.

Comment: @ Daniel: What is meant by $\Omega$ symbol?

Comment: $f\in \Omega(g)$ if there exists a $c > 0$ with $\lvert f(x)\rvert \geqslant c\cdot g(x)$ for all large enough $x$ (or $x$ close enough to $x_0$ if you're looking at the asymptotics for $x\to x_0$).

Comment: $f=\Omega(g)$ means that $f$ is bounded below by $g$.

Comment: Oh...then can we say if $B=O(p)$ and $A=\Omega(p^{-1})$, $AB = O(p)\Omega(p^{-1})$ is diverging as A is bounded below.

Comment: @Daniel: Can you give any reference to that result: if $A \in O(p^{2})$, then $A^{−1/2} \in \Omega(p^{−1})$?

Comment: $\lvert A\rvert \leqslant K\cdot p^2 \Rightarrow \lvert A\rvert^{1/2} \leqslant \sqrt{K}\cdot p \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{K}\cdot p} \leqslant \lvert A\rvert^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reference. Well, they state that if $A = \mathcal{O}(p^2)$ then $\mathcal{O}(p\cdot A^{-1/2})$ **can** diverge. Take a look at Grandi's serie which is $1-1+1-1\ldots$ which is in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ but does diverge.

Comment: Yes, I get your point. But how can we show this mathematically? In that paper, how can we say it is diverging? Do you have any idea?

Comment: They are not saying that it is diverging. Only that it is possible. I think they want to say that even if you have a good estimator for the first eigenvector does not mean that the matrix is converging. Or else, we just cannot say anything about the convergence of $\hat \Sigma$

Comment: Hmmm..yes can be. If $f(x) = x^2 + 5x + 8$ is it wrong to say $ f(x) = O(x^2)$?

Comment: No, this is correct. $f(x)$ is in $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$. But $f(x)$ in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ does not imply any convergence (nor divergence) of $f$.

Comment: In this case $f(x) = O(x^2)$, since for $x > 1$ we have $x^2 > x$, so this leads to $|f(x)| \le |x^2| + 5|x^2| + 8|x^2| = 14|x^2|$ and thus $f(x) = O(x^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

We say that $f = O(g)$ (as $x \to \infty$) if there exists a constant $M > 0$ and a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$|f(x)| \le M | g(x) |$$ for all $x > x_0$.  This just gives us upper bounds.  Take for instance $A(p) = 1$ (a constant function) and $B(p) = 1/p$, then trivially we have $A = O(p^2)$ and $B = O(p)$.  However $A^{-1/2} B = 1/p$, and converges to 0 as $p \to \infty$.

Comment: @ Joel: If $B(p) = 1/p$, then isn't it implies $ B=O(p^{-1})$ rather than $O(p)$?

Comment: Big oh is simply a statement about upper bounds.  If $B = p^{-1}$, then we know that for $p > 1$ we have $B = 1/p \le 1 |p|$.  This means that $B = O(p)$.  We also have $B = O(p^{-1})$ and $B = O(p^{2})$.